# 4017 decade counters

Tags: led

I was hoping someone here might have an answer for this - is there a version of the 4017 decade counter that is TTL, not CMOS? I'd like to create a project for a bunch of 11 - 12 year olds and I just know they would kill any CMOS chip as soon as they handled it, even with static protection. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A simple search for `TTL decade counter IC` in Google can give you a lot of answers :)

Comment: Stick with the 4017. They're very cheap. Teach the kids about static and handling. It may depend on your location though. I'm in Ireland (damp) and never had any CMOS static problems and never had to worry about it.

Comment: Still CMOS, but the 74HC4017 should be more ESD resistant than the old fragile CD4017 CMOS types.

Comment: Tony, is this a project where you could "build" a larger module out of IC parts that "behaves like" a TTL version? Since you are talking about 11-12 yr olds, I guess I'm just thinking about things like ["snap" electronics modules](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000IXMP6Q).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and comments folks. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and comments folks. Very much appreciated! Just so you know, the project I'm making (for about 100 kids) is an electronic dice as a STEM activity. We've already made a simple "buzzer" using a 555 so they are familiar with its working. The engineering part of STEM requires a solution to a problem, in this case how can we "modernise" regular dice used in mathematics. My hope is to inspire a lot more thought about future career paths (engineering, maths, science...) for these little minds.

Comment: Oh, and jonk, I'm really trying to avoid pre made modules such as the one you suggest. I really want the kids to make as much of the cct as they can - including the housing. but thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

No, so buy spares they're cheap! (I'm seeing under 20c at element 14)

The common "B" suffix parts seem to have pretty good anti-static protection already, but I've not tried to bust them.

Answer (score 0):

4017 "Johnson Counter" only became  viable with CMOS not TTL with the lower power dissipation needed in a DIP package.

CD4017 have >300 ohm drivers @ 12V , ~ 1k @5V

74HC4017 have ~50 Ohm drivers @ 5V  Use this to drive LEDs with 330R easily or even 50R with more power and share the R for  all LEDs with common Anode to 5V.

Here is a simple traffic light example [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.0012%2019.867427341514983%2050%205%2050%0A163%20296%20336%20320%20336%201%2010%200%200%205%200%200%200%200%200%200%200%0AR%20456%20368%20456%20392%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A152%20336%20296%20336%20232%201%204%205%205%0Aw%20320%20296%20312%20296%200%0Aw%20312%20296%20312%20320%200%0Aw%20328%20296%20328%20320%200%0Aw%20344%20296%20344%20320%200%0Aw%20352%20296%20360%20296%200%0Aw%20360%20296%20360%20320%200%0Aw%20408%20296%20408%20320%200%0Aw%20424%20296%20424%20320%200%0Aw%20400%20296%20392%20296%200%0Aw%20392%20296%20392%20320%200%0Aw%20432%20296%20440%20296%200%0Aw%20440%20296%20440%20320%200%0A152%20416%20296%20416%20232%201%204%200%205%0A162%20480%2088%20528%2088%202%20old-default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A162%20480%20120%20528%20120%202%20old-default-led%201%201%200%200.01%0A162%20480%20152%20528%20152%202%20old-default-led%200%201%200%200.01%0Aw%20376%20320%20376%20216%200%0A162%20304%2088%20256%2088%202%20old-default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A162%20304%20120%20256%20120%202%20old-default-led%201%201%200%200.01%0A162%20304%20152%20256%20152%202%20old-default-led%200%201%200%200.01%0Aw%20336%20232%20336%20152%200%0Aw%20456%20320%20456%20120%200%0Aw%20456%20120%20480%20120%200%0Aw%20416%20232%20416%20152%200%0Aw%20416%20152%20480%20152%200%0Aw%20416%2096%20416%20152%200%0Aw%20416%2080%20432%2080%200%0Aw%20432%2080%20432%20120%200%0Aw%20432%20120%20456%20120%200%0Aw%20336%20152%20336%2040%200%0Aw%20360%2088%20304%2088%200%0Aw%20376%20216%20352%20216%200%0Aw%20336%20152%20304%20152%200%0Aw%20352%20216%20352%20120%200%0Aw%20352%20120%20304%20120%200%0Aw%20352%20120%20352%2056%200%0A152%20352%2048%20480%2048%201%202%205%205%0Aw%20336%2040%20352%2040%200%0Aw%20480%2048%20480%2088%200%0Aw%20528%2088%20528%20120%200%0Aw%20528%20120%20528%20152%200%0Aw%20256%2088%20256%20120%200%0Aw%20256%20120%20256%20152%200%0Ar%20528%20152%20528%20216%200%20200%0Ar%20256%20152%20256%20216%200%20200%0Ag%20256%20216%20256%20232%200%0Ag%20528%20216%20528%20232%200%0A152%20416%2088%20360%2088%201%202%200%205%0AR%20152%20176%20152%20136%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20152%20176%2064%20176%200%0Ar%2064%20240%2064%20304%200%2047000%0Ar%2064%20176%2064%20240%200%2010000%0Aw%20216%20272%20216%20352%200%0Aw%20216%20352%20296%20352%200%0A165%2088%20208%20152%20208%204%204.999999950000001%0Aw%2064%20304%2064%20336%200%0Ac%2064%20336%2064%20368%200%200.000009999999999999999%203.141860626714851%0Ag%2064%20368%2064%20384%200%0Aw%2064%20240%2088%20240%200%0Aw%2064%20304%2088%20304%200%0Aw%2064%20336%2088%20336%200%0Aw%20152%20176%20216%20176%200%0Aw%20216%20176%20216%20240%200%0Ag%20184%20368%20184%20376%200%0)

[image]

Also include the 74HC4060 clk ripple counter. as a Schmitt Trigger Astable clock. instead of 555  for variable tap /2 cascaded clks.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much Tony. You have given me an idea for another simple project for my kids down the track.

Answer (score 0):

7490 is a decade counter IC. You might have different pin outs.

Comment: Care to elaborate?